# Selenium - Contains Text - Is possible to search for specific/literal text

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to define specific text within selenium when searching for elements containing text. I am currently using `"//tr/td[contains(text.."` however I am having an issue as there are duplicate names in the xpath. E.G. I want to find the xpath name 'ABC123', however selenium is also picking up xpath name 'ABC1234'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide us the html for same and then describe the issue you are facing.

Comment: try to create the unique xpath. Use the tag names in the xpath accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
//tr/td[text()='ABC123']
```

it should find exact text